# Bootstrap coding text overwrite

Tags: javascript, text, twitter-bootstrap, compiler-errors, overlapping

I'm going to say I'm not smart enough to figure this one out. I'm using spacelab version of Twitter's bootstrap. 50% of the time I refresh the page looks like this. The other half the time it loads fine.  What might be causing this???! https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzy3b.png

It seems to not happen when I disable JS. Which script might be the culprit?

```
<script>
$(document).scroll(function(){
    // If has not activated (has no attribute "data-top"
    if (!$('.subnav').attr('data-top')) {
        // If already fixed, then do nothing
        if ($('.subnav').hasClass('subnav-fixed')) return;
        // Remember top position
        var offset = $('.subnav').offset()
        $('.subnav').attr('data-top', offset.top);
    }

    if ($('.subnav').attr('data-top') - $('.subnav').outerHeight() <= $(this).scrollTop())
        $('.subnav').addClass('subnav-fixed');
    else
        $('.subnav').removeClass('subnav-fixed');
});

</script>

<!-- Le javascript
================================================== -->


<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="http://bootswatch.com/js/bsa.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/application.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootswatch.js"></script>
```

Comment: Since it is intermittent it might be a resource failing to load or a script execution order problem.  Can you post the full page markup or provide a zip? Which browser are you using?